# node js and npm not avalible after restart of zimaboard

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

I want to install nodejs on my zimaboard with casaos and use these instructions: https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation
with version v18.16.0 from the download page.
I follow the steps from this category: https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation#how-to-install-nodejs-via-binary-archive-on-linux and installed it, then I ran node -v and the other commands and it works, I can start my applications but after I restarted the miniserver I can't use these commands. Does anyone have an idea why I can't use them?